# Sonarcloud not displaying issues for .net core app using dotnet-sonarscanner

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarcloud

I've created a test console app using .net core 3.1, added it to github, and setup a GitHub action using the template provided by Sonarcloud.io.

The build analysis part looks like this:

```
      .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"<projectkey>" /o:"<org>" /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" /d:sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version=true
      dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}"
```

This builds fine and reports no errors. Yet when I go to sonarcloud.io although I can see it's received the analysis, it's not showing any issues, despite my purposely adding some:

The master branch displays this:

[image]

Yet, the code is visible in the code tab:

[image]

For PRs I see:

[image]

But there *are* issues (I can see them locally when using SonarLint pointing at sonarcloud.io).

What am I missing?

Comment: Provide the property `sonar.sources=.` in `.\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner begin`

Comment: @SouravAtta after doing that I get this error: `File Program.cs can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files`

Comment: Program.cs file is getting indexed twice means you can exclude it once using sonar properties `sonar.exclusions=<path of file>` This will resolve the issue.

Comment: I've added `/d:sonar.sources=. /d:sonar.exclusions=/SonarQubeTest/Program.cs` and it still gives the same error for indexing twice. Confused though why I'd want to specify the sources folder (the root with `.`) then exclude files? Surely I don't want them excluded?

Comment: Do you have Program.cs somewhere else also, other than src folder. In `sonar.sources`, just give the source folder like this `sonar.source=src\**` Does SonarQubeTest is your source folder ?

Comment: I think I've figured out the duplicate issue, it was because the test path defaults to the root, so it would have been analyzed twice. I've now got `/d:sonar.sources=/src /d:sonar.tests=/tests` and it runs without error again. But still I don't see any issues in sonarcloud....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't showing any issues because it was considering all my files as test code. I had created this whole repo as a Sonarcloud test, and my project was called `SonarCloudTest.csproj` and Sonar has some regex rules around categorising code.